# rpmbuild hp-be2net emulex driver

Tags: linux, driver

i am trying to do an rpmbuild for HP DL360 G7 Emulex driver from HP on centos 6.3

but it fails with this error.. any ideas?

```
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd hp-be2net-4.1.402.6
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ export 'EXTRA_CFLAGS=-DVERSION=\"4.1.402.6\"'
+ EXTRA_CFLAGS='-DVERSION=\"4.1.402.6\"'
+ for flavor in default
+ rm -rf obj/default
+ cp -r source obj/default
+ export SRC=/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/hp-be2net-4.1.402.6/obj/default
+ SRC=/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/hp-be2net-4.1.402.6/obj/default
++ '[' default = default ']'
+ make -C /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64 modules M=/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/hp-be2net-4.1.402.6/obj/default CONFIG_BE2NET=m
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/hp-be2net-4.1.402.6/obj/default/be_main.o
/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/hp-be2net-4.1.402.6/obj/default/be_main.c: In function 'get_rx_page_info':
/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/hp-be2net-4.1.402.6/obj/default/be_main.c:1279: error: 'struct be_rx_page_info' has no member named 'bus'
/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/hp-be2net-4.1.402.6/obj/default/be_main.c: In function 'be_post_rx_frags':
/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/hp-be2net-4.1.402.6/obj/default/be_main.c:1679: error: 'struct be_rx_page_info' has no member named 'bus'
make[1]: *** [/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/hp-be2net-4.1.402.6/obj/default/be_main.o] Error 1
make: *** [_module_/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/hp-be2net-4.1.402.6/obj/default] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64'
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.R3DzsV (%build)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. HP has not provided me with a resolution yet so I started looking around for other possible solutions. I found that Emulex (the manufacturer of the card) provides a binary driver compatible with RHEL 6.2 that seems to load fine in RHEL 6.3.

Look for UCNA Ethernet Driver - Binary Driver RPM Kit
http://www.emulex.com/downloads/emulex/linux/rhel6x/drivers.html

Comment: yeah i had to wait for some time, there is a new kernel release for centos 6.3 which fixed the issue...try an yum update...that fixed it..